# Работа с текстовыми файлами

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Работаю в Vusial Studio. У нас есть текстовый файл, в котором содержится несколько строк:

> `{000} {SampleText1}
> {001} {SampleText2}
> {010} {SampleText3}
> {011} {System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100500)}`

(Вместо `{}` любые разграничивающие знаки, может быть какая-то последовательность - это не принципиально.)

Метод вернул значение 001. Нужно вывести на экран SampleText2.

Заранее благодарен.

P.S. Был бы еще более благодарен, если бы рассказали, как по значению 011 программа бы выполнила текст, содержащийся в файле (на ум приходит проверка значения текста и потом, отдельной функцией, выполнение заранее записаных строк.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то в текстовом файле находится таблица код - значение. В том случае, когда ваш метод вернул некий код, вы хотите найти в файле строку, содержащую этот код, и вывести соответсвующее значение.

Для этого достаточно:

1. Считать текстовый файл в словарь.
2. Извлечь из словаря значение по ключу, равному коду.
3. Выполнить (при необходимости) код по ключу.

Чтение файла в словарь:

```
string[] from = File.ReadAllLines("from.txt");
var dictionary = from.Select(l => l.Split('|')).ToDictionary(w => w[0], w => w[1]);
```

Этот код читает файл в массив строк, проходит по каждой строке, разбивает каждую на правую и левую части, используя разделитель "|" и помещает их в словарь.

Теперь вывести на экран по коду key строку просто:

```
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key)) {
    Console.WriteLine(dictionary[key]);
}
```

Выполнение кода - отдельная история. Это можно сделать на основе [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx), [DynamicMethod.GetILGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xcbx21sk.aspx)

Comment: Я понял принцип в общих чертах, но осталось несколько неопределенностей.
файл будет иметь вид:"000 | SampleText1 001 | SampleText2"
и после этого при получении значения 001 он будет выводить SampleText2?

Comment: Файл будет иметь формат:

>`000 | Текст 000
001 | Текст 001
...`

Comment: И соотвественно можно будет вызывать значения из файла по этим ключам, изменять значения по ключам, работать с ними, сравнивать их друг с другом и прочие прелести?

Comment: Все, во всем разобрался, благодарствую. Но остались некоторые вопросы по кодировки и использовании спец. знаков вроде переноса строки (\n) как можно задать перенос строки внутри txt файла?